# How can I hang a shelf on a paneled wall of a mobile home?

Tags: walls

I would like to hang a shelf on the wall of my Mobile Home. This is my first mobile home, it's a 1977. The wall are paneled. Should I use a toggle bolt? If so, EXACTLY how do I use one?

Comment: Is it a manufactured home that is permanently attached to a foundation or a mobile home on wheels?

Answer (score 1):

Most mobile homes have studs, though they are often smaller than the 2x4s you'd find in a house.  If you can't find the studs, or don't want to attach the shelf to the studs. You can use toggle bolts to attach the shelf to the wall, though the weight capacity of the shelf may be limited.

Follow the [manufacturers installation instructions](http://www.powers.com/pdfs/plastic/togglebolt.pdf), to install the shelf using toggle bolts.

[image: Toggle Bolt Installation]

The manufacturers documentation should also list what materials are suitable to use the toggle bolts with, and the load capacity of the toggle bolt.